# An empty space is there instead of the video which needed to be autoplayed

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, video

I've looked all over the internet but this issue does not seems to be resolved. I'm seeing an empty space instead of the video in ios device. Works fine in android or my hp laptop.

```
<video
          autoPlay
          loop
          muted
          playsInLine
          src={homepage}
          type="video/mp4"
          className={classes.videoContainer}
        />
```

Everyone says to just add playsInLine and life would be easier but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What is the URL being passed to video?

Comment: It's saved in the assets folder in the src and I'm importing it like this 'import homepage from "../../../assets/videos/homepage.mp4";'
working fine on android/ windows browser but not on ios devices @Khalil

Answer (score 0):

Try using `playsInline` instead of `playsInLine`. Also, add webkit-playsinline={true}.

Comment: A bit out of context, but can react lazy load can hinder playing videos

Comment: Since its working on Android and Desktop, no it won't affect the video.